# Recode many groups of variables corresponding to letters A, B, etc. based on another group of variables with corresponding ending

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(var1_A=c(1,2,0,5,NA),var1_B=c(1,1,NA,0,3),var1_C=c(1,NA,1,1,0),
           var1_D=c(1,1,NA,0,3),var1_E=c(1,2,0,5,NA),var1_F=c(1,2,NA,1,0),
           var1_G=c(1,2,NA,5,NA),var1_H=c(1,NA,1,0,3),var1_I=c(1,NA,2,1,0), 
           ideology2_A=c(2,2,2,3,4), ideology2_B=c(NA,3,3,1,4), 
           ideology2_C=c(1,4,7,6,9), ideology2_D=c(8,9,7,6,4), 
           ideology2_E=c(NA,9,5,6,4),
           ideology2_F=c(1,1,1,1,4), ideology2_G=c(8,9,7,6,4), 
           ideology2_H=c(8,9,7,6,5), ideology2_I=c(8,9,8,9,8),
           ex_ideology_A=c(3,3,3,3,4), ex_ideology_B=c(3,NA,3,1,4), 
           ex_ideology_C=c(1,4,7,6,NA),ex_ideology_D=c(3,3,3,NA,0),
           ex_ideology_E=c(3,NA,3,1,1), ex_ideology_F = c(1,1,1,2,3),
           ex_ideology_G=c(1,2,3,4,5), ex_ideology_H=c(1,1,1,1,1)
           ex_ideology_I=c(2,2,2,NA,1), no_change_A=c(1,1,1,1,1),
           no_change_B=c(2,2,2,2,2), no_change_C=c(1,1,1,1,1),
           no_change_D=c(1,3,3,1,NA), no_change_E=c(1,1,1,1,1),
           no_change_F=c(0,0,1,1,1), no_change_G=c(1,1,2,2,2),
           no_change_H=c(5,6,7,8,9), no_change_I=c(1,1,1,1,1)
           country=c("BRA","USA","URU,"BRA","UK"),
           ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), v5=c(6:10))
```

I need to recode all values in the groups of variables which have the word "ideology" corresponding to each variable with same letter in var1. More especifically, whenever var1_A == 0 or var1_A == NA, recode ideology2_A and ex_ideology3_A to NA, and so on with var1_B, etc. In fact it would be more appropriate to generate NEW variables, preserving the original ones (like dplyr's "mutate", not "transmute").

My real data has many more columns and 60k rows, but the columns involved in this problem would be only these three groups of 9, indexed by letters (there are other groups of variables also indexed with those letters, just like "no_change" in the example above, but that should not interfere with the solution).

EDIT: my example dataset now is closer to the real data I need to work with. In the first version of the post it was a dataset with only 3 columns for each group of variables (letters A to C) and all groups with similar names (var1, var2, var3). It also did not have other variables than the benchmark and the ones to recode.

Answer (score 2):

What about this base R option

```
do.call(
  cbind,
  lapply(
    unname(u <- split.default(mydata, gsub(".*_", "", names(mydata)))),
    function(x) cbind(x[1], x[-1] * ifelse(x[[1]] %in% c(0, NA), NA, 1))
  )
)[match(c(sapply(u, names)), names(mydata))]
```

which gives

```
  var1_A var1_B var1_C var2_A var2_B var2_C var3_A var3_B var3_C
1      1      1      1      2     NA      1      3      3      1
2      2      1     NA      2      3     NA      3     NA     NA
3      0     NA      1     NA     NA      7     NA     NA      7
4      5      0      1      3     NA      6      3     NA      6
5     NA      3      0     NA      4     NA     NA      4     NA
```

---

If you want to create recoded columns and preserve the original ones, try the code below

```
do.call(
  cbind,
  lapply(
    unname(u <- split.default(mydata, gsub(".*_", "", names(mydata)))),
    function(x) cbind(x, x[-1] * ifelse(x[[1]] %in% c(0, NA), NA, 1))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  var1_A var2_A var3_A var2_A var3_A var1_B var2_B var3_B var2_B var3_B var1_C
1      1      2      3      2      3      1     NA      3     NA      3      1
2      2      2      3      2      3      1      3     NA      3     NA     NA
3      0      2      3     NA     NA     NA      3      3     NA     NA      1
4      5      3      3      3      3      0      1      1     NA     NA      1
5     NA      4      4     NA     NA      3      4      4      4      4      0
  var2_C var3_C var2_C var3_C
1      1      1      1      1
2      4      4     NA     NA
3      7      7      7      7
4      6      6      6      6
5      9     NA     NA     NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(var1_A = c(1, 2, 0, 5, NA), var1_B = c(1, 1, NA, 
0, 3), var1_C = c(1, NA, 1, 1, 0), var2_A = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 4),
    var2_B = c(NA, 3, 3, 1, 4), var2_C = c(1, 4, 7, 6, 9), var3_A = c(3,
    3, 3, 3, 4), var3_B = c(3, NA, 3, 1, 4), var3_C = c(1, 4,
    7, 6, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to work very well. Would there be an easy way into this base R code to make it create new variables (recoded versions of var2_A, etc.), preserving the original versions?

Answer (score 1):

Using varios pivots:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "key", values_to = "values") %>% 
  separate(key, c("var", "letter")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = values) %>% 
  mutate(
    var2 = if_else(var1 == 0 | is.na(var1), NA_real_, var2),
    var3 = if_else(var1 == 0 | is.na(var1), NA_real_, var3),
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("var"), names_to = "var", values_to = "values") %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(var, letter, sep = "_")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = row, names_from = name, values_from = values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the solution by @eastclintw00d, but with slightly different approach.

```
tmp <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(obs = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-obs, 
     names_pattern="(.*)_(.*)", 
     names_to=c("vars", "letter"), 
     values_to="vals") %>% 
  group_by(letter, obs) %>% 
  mutate(val1 = vals[which(vars == "var1")], 
         new = case_when(val1 == 0 | is.na(val1) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ vals)) %>% 
  select(-val1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("vars", "letter"), 
              values_from=c("vals", "new"))
names(tmp) <- gsub("vals_", "", names(tmp))
```

---

### EDIT: to work with updated data

This should work with the updated data.  The difference is how the variables to be pivoted are selected - it finds variables that end with and underscore and any capital letter.  The `ends_with()` function didn't seem to work with the regular expression, so I used `str_detect()` from `stringr` wrapped in `which()`.

```
tmp <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(obs = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(which(str_detect(names(.), "_[A-Z]")), 
               names_pattern="(.*)_(.*)", 
               names_to=c("vars", "letter"), 
               values_to="vals") %>% 
  group_by(letter, obs) %>% 
  mutate(val1 = vals[which(vars == "var1")], 
         new = case_when(val1 == 0 | is.na(val1) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ vals)) %>% 
  select(-val1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("vars", "letter"), 
              values_from=c("vals", "new"))
names(tmp) <- gsub("vals_", "", names(tmp))
```

Comment: I really liked that approach, I don't have to specify "var2, var3". If it's not asking much, would there be an easy way to get something like that with groups of variables of completely different names. I mean where we have var1 would be a specific name, like "share_votes_A" , etc., while what I am calling "var2", etc. are named something different. I put these names to make it clearer but forgot that could bring easier solutions that do not apply with specific names. Which is not a big problem, I can just change names and then change them back.

Comment: @GuilhermePiresArbache I think the approach above should work even if the variables are named something different - the thing you would have to change is on line 8 where it says `which(vars == "var1")`, you'd have to put whatever the benchmark variable is.  For the solution above to work as is, the stem of the variable (i.e., the part before the underscore and letter at the end) could not have any underscores in it.  The `pivot_longer()` function used above splits the variable names on the underscore.

Comment: Sorry, I am not being very clear.  I've tested your solution and the problem doesn't seem to be the name of the benchmark variable.The problem is I have many other variables (that is not a problem, I can create a new dataset with select then bind everything together), and also I have 8 letters, not just 3, in my real data. I can't find in the code where does it tell me to go as far as 3 letters only, but that is what's happening. Sorry, I was trying to make it easier for everyone by using a simpler example but I guess I'm only making it harder.

Comment: @GuilhermePiresArbache If you want to post an edit to the question with a more realistic example, perhaps we could try to puzzle out the answer.

Comment: Now I guess the only big difference is that the real data has much more rows and many other columns too, but I have put some other columns that should not change, and I have also put the 9 (not 8, as I said before) variables for each group indexed by letters. It should be sufficient to reach what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @GuilhermePiresArbache I edited the answer, check to make sure that it works as intended.